# How to remove sticky post capability for a specific user role?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, permissions, sticky-post, featured-post

All is in the title. Does someone know a way to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though may not be intuitive, one needs the capability `edit_others_posts` to make posts sticky. If you don't want a user to have that ability just remove the `edit_others_posts` capability from the user.